# functions.php return custom text

Tags: functions, multisite

I am looking to add custom text to the site in functions.php.

I am using multisite. Is there a hook to determine which site so I can alter the text?

For example:

```
function greeting(){
    if(site_name('one'){
    echo 'hello';
    } elseif(site_name('two')){
    echo 'goodbye';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to alter the text. Please be more specific.

Comment: @kaiser Below the header in the main part of the index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`get_blog_details()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details)** to do it.

Use it the following way:--

```
function greeting() {
    global $blog_id;
    $current_blog = get_blog_details( $blog_id );

    if ( 'one' == $current_blog->blogname ) {
        echo 'hello';
    } elseif ( 'two' == $current_blog->blogname ) {
        echo 'goodbye';
    }
}
```